# R Shiny Plot Output Error "Error:: object 'xx' not found"

Tags: r, shiny

Really frustrating issue here! I have a plot that will work in my local environment but when it is wrapped in `renderPlot()` throws an error.

The dataframe has long lines of wrangling code, so, to simplify this question I have truncated the data sourcing to one line `data = allData` for the purpose of this example.

I am getting the error message *Error: object 'runtime' not found*, which is one of the features in the dataframe I am using. When I add in `x = data$runtime` and `data$filtSpeed` I get a blank plot... When I run the plot line of code on its own, I get the plot I want.

This is the code

```
server = function(input, output, session) {
    data = reactive(allData)
    
    output$plot = renderPlotly({
        data = allData
        plot_ly(data, x = ~runtime, y = ~filtSpeed, type = 'scatter', mode = 'line')
    })
}

ui = basicPage(
    h1("Title here"),
    plotOutput('plot')
)

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any idea's in how to solve this issue or where I am going wrong?

**UPDATE**

I am working with raw gps data which I have calculated the distance and speed based on the latitude, longitude and sample frequency into the data frame.
I have multiple sessions as .gpx files on the PC which I have looped over to read them in, create the speed and distance, store in a list and rbind them all together as a dataframe.

The code is essentially doing the following:

```
library(plotKML) #for reading gpx documents

folder <- 'gpx_files/'
files = list.files(path = folder, pattern = "*.gpx")
numfiles = length(files)
datalist = list()

for (file in files){
    data = readGPX(paste0(folder, file))
    data = as.data.frame(data$tracks[[1]])

    ##**a bunch more wrangling**##

    data = data %>% filter(filtSpeed > 8)

    datalist[[file]] = data
}

allData = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, datalist))

head(allData)
```

And producing:

| lon | lat | ele | time | Date | hz | runtime | dist | filtSpeed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 153.37 | -28.01 | 0.4 | 20-12-10 00:18:13 | 2020-12-10 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 153.37 | -28.01 | 1.2 | 20-12-10 00:18:14 | 2020-12-10 | 1 | 2 | 2.9 | 9.5 |
| 153.37 | -28.01 | 1.8 | 20-12-10 00:18:15 | 2020-12-10 | 1 | 3 | 8.7 | 14.7 |
| 153.37 | -28.01 | 1.8 | 20-12-10 00:18:16 | 2020-12-10 | 1 | 4 | 13.9 | 17.2 |
| 153.37 | -28.01 | 1.8 | 20-12-10 00:18:17 | 2020-12-10 | 1 | 5 | 20.5 | 18.4 |

**...**             **...**             **...**

| lon | lat | ele | time | Date | hz | runtime | dist | filtSpeed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 153.37 | -28.01 | 0.4 | 20-12-28 00:18:13 | 2020-12-28 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 153.37 | -28.01 | 1.2 | 20-12-28 00:18:14 | 2020-12-28 | 1 | 2 | 4.8 | 10.2 |
| 153.37 | -28.01 | 1.8 | 20-12-28 00:18:15 | 2020-12-28 | 1 | 3 | 8.6 | 13.7 |
| 153.37 | -28.01 | 1.8 | 20-12-28 00:18:16 | 2020-12-28 | 1 | 4 | 16.4 | 16.2 |
| 153.37 | -28.01 | 1.8 | 20-12-28 00:18:17 | 2020-12-28 | 1 | 5 | 21.5 | 16.4 |

Comment: Since `data` is reactive, use `plot_ly(data(), x = ~runtime, ....)` (note the parenthesis).

Comment: Replace `plotOutput('plot')` with `plotlyOutput('plot')`

Comment: Hi MrFlick, I have also tried this with no success :(

Comment: Hi YBS, I still get the same issue with plotlyOutput too

Comment: Can you provide data in a reproducible format?

Comment: Where do you have your for loop with the data wrangling?  Is it outside of the server function?  Did you try to wrap it in a reactive()?

Comment: Does it work if you try a simple ggplot instead of the plotly?

Comment: ggplot hasn't worked either. The loop is outside of the server function, yes. How would I wrap it the reactive? As in:

reactive(
    for (file in files) {
          blah blah blah
    }
)

Answer (score 0):

You code works fine if I replace your data with cars data.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  #data = reactive(allData)
  data <- cars %>% mutate(filtSpeed=speed, runtime=dist)
  output$plot = renderPlotly({
    #data = allData
    plot_ly(data, x = ~runtime, y = ~filtSpeed, type = 'scatter', mode = 'line')
  })
}

ui = basicPage(
  h1("Testing with cars data"),
  plotlyOutput('plot')
)

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks YBS, I can get the plot to work if I use a different data frame. I've got a loop running a cleaning code over multiple files and binding them together for a single data frame output. When I use one of the individual data frames, the app runs fine, but it is when I use the binded data frame that the code doesn't work..

Comment: Perhaps you should post the code - defining binded data frame, into your question as that seems to be the issue.  Also, please post some sample data you are using.